# Ads embedded in phone apps - what is accessible?

Tags: android, iphone

Imagine you are developing a "free" app for android & iPhone and want to refinance yourself through using some sketchy ad service. Does an app developer have to worry that the ad content he embeds can access information such as the user's phone number or maybe even his phonebook? Furthermore, is there some danger that the user's phone number can be made public if he clicks on the ad?

Naively I would imagine that all this information is safe on both android and iPhone. Hearing from many stolen phone numbers I was however wondering on what technical ground the access to such private information is "granted"?

I'm happy about general answers or more specific answers just covering one device type.

Answer (score 1):

It actually depends on the implementation.

If the ad service just needs to pull a randomly chosen image from a website query then there is no risk at all there.

If the ad service needs a query to a page which needs to run javascript(Or other type of code execution) then there might be a information leak but ONLY if the app is able to do so for example with androids permission system an app that can only display UIs wont be able to read the phones data.